It's possible to have different potentials (boundary conditions) in the surface of a cylindrical conductor?
Edit I realized that my problem is not clearly stated.
In general, I can solve the Laplace equation for boundary conditions $V(r,\phi, z=0) = f(r,\phi)$ (bottom of the cylinder), $V(r,\phi, z=L) = g(r,\phi)$ (top of the cylinder) and $V(r=a,\phi, z) = h(\phi,z)$ (at the curved surface).
My question
Do these kind of boundary conditions make sense from a physicist's point of view, for a right circular conductor, being the Laplace equation for the electric potential? What about a hollow cylinder?
My understanding
I understand that if this is a conductor, the electric field must be zero inside of it; this means that the electric potential must be constant. From this I can assume that we can have grounded caps and curved surface, grounded caps and not-grounded curved surface, or grounded curved surface and not-grounded caps held at the same potential, but we cannot have general boundary conditions in each surface.
Is this assumption correct?
Thanks in advance for your help.

An ideal conductor of any shape will have a constant potential everywhere in its volume and on its surface. If you are modeling a conductor as the surface of a "tin can" (finite cylindrical sides with two "caps"), then the potential must be constant at every point on this surface. Therefore, the sides and caps must all have the same value of the potential.
In an ideal situation, the word "grounded" means "connected to a source or sink of charge, which can supply or absorb as much current as needed without changing its potential." Therefore, it does not matter "which part" of a conductor you connect to ground. If you connect, say, the side of the tin can to ground, then the side of the tin can will have the same potential as the ground. Because the surface of a perfect conductor has the same potential everywhere, then the rest of the surface of the tin can (including the caps) will also be at the same potential as the ground.
You can have other boundary conditions on a surface for other kinds of materials. Also, you should be aware that real life conductors are generally not ideal conductors (although they can be approximated as ideal conductors in many situations). But ideal conductors must have a constant value of the potential everywhere within and on their surface.

Thank you for your answer. I assume that an ideal hollow conductor behaves the same way. So, in order to avoid opening a new question, if the material is not a conductor, can I have any combination of boundary conditions?

@kurush A hollow conductor is not a special case -- the general statement is still "a conductor has the same potential everywhere in its volume and on its surface." If you are modeling a hollow cylinder as a two dimensional surface, then you can ignore the clause "everywhere in its volume." I hesitate to say "combination of boundary conditions" -- for a given boundary value problem (BVP), you have one set of boundary conditions. However, you are right in that other materials will have different boundary conditions than the ones for an ideal conductor.

I'm sorry for insisting; that's the problem of a non-physicist trying to make sense of things. So, in a dielectric for example, I can have a potential in one cap, another in the other one, and a different one in the curved surface?

@kurush For a dielectric, typically you would solve the problem using the displacement field to account for the effect of bound charges in the material. Stepping back, my mental picture of an arbitrary distribution of charge on the surface of a material amounts to "painting" the surface of a material with "charged paint." (This then translates into Neuman boundary conditions (BCs), or BCs on the gradient of the potential at the surface). This doesn't correspond to something you can do in a lab easily but is useful conceptually.

For a realistic material, you need to think through what boundary conditions make sense given the electronic properties of the material. In other words, the mathematics tells us what kinds of BCs are necessary to uniquely determine the solution. But, the appropriate BCs for a specific problem is determined by the physics of the situation. So there is no general prescription, you either need to argue your material can be modeled by a standard class (eg conductor or linear dielectric), or you need to determine what BCs make sense.

The problem statement doesn't say it's a conductor. If it's not a conductor, you can theoretically set the potential of the surface to be anything you like. A common practical approach is a collection of electrodes on an insulating surface connected by a network of resistors with current driven through them.

Yes, but the problem statement only gave birth to my doubt. If it's a conductor, then the possible boundary conditions are limited as I guessed?

@kurush If it's a conductor, the boundary condition is that the electric field parallel to the surface is zero. You should be able to deduce the very simple range of possibilities from that.
